# Degradation of AC signals as inputs of inverter amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal

i recently, did a configuration of an inverter op amp model and i fed it with an analog signal of the form$$S(t)=2sin(1000t\pi)$$

As you may know, the general response of an inverter Op Amp (741), is the additive inverse of the resistance pluggers to the output and the one plugged to the input, times the input signal. When put high values of R2, the oscilloscope wave form change and it looks like a square signal, i wonder if anyone knows why is that, is that behavior related to the system, the IC, the oscilloscope. Is that related with FT in any way?
Thank you very much.

Implemented ciruit: (R2=10k), (R1=100 ohms) (vcc=15)
[image]
Input signal:
[image]
Output signal:
[image]

Comment: It shouldn't do that if you wired it up correctly. Can you show a circuit of what you did - maybe you made a mistake. Show values too. What is FT and CI?

Comment: Off course, how do i add images here?

Comment: Once you have enough reputation, you see an image icon when editing a question. Prior to that, just upload to any free image hosting site, and paste the links into the question or comments, and someone will incorporate them into the question for you.

Comment: What is the supply voltage and what are the peak-to-peak voltages of the input and the output signals? The 741 has a fairly high headroom requirement, i.e. it does not accept inputs all the way to the V+ or V- rails, it does not output anywhere close to the V+ and V- rails.

Comment: FT- fourier transform

Comment: IC -integrated circuit

Comment: Your input is sin(1000tπ) and *not* 2.sin(1000tπ)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're railing your op-amp.

Basically, the output can't swing to the power rails. As such, even though your circuit has a gain of 100, the *maximum* voltage you could ever reasonably expect to get out of the output would be +-15V.

Note that this maximum is *independent of the gain*.

There are basically two things you can do. You can increase your power supply voltages, or decrease your input signal magnitude.

---

Note that no real op-amp can ever swing *completely* to the rails. A modern rail-rail output op-amp may swing to a few millivolts of the rails.

However, you're using the ancient (and extremely crappy) 741 op amp. This is **not** a rail-rail op-amp. From the [741 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf):

> VS = ±15V
>   RL ≥ 10 kΩ
>   Min: ±12v
>   Typ: ±14v

You can see with ±15V rails, and a 10 kΩ load on the output (what you have), the output swing is typically +14V - -14V, with a worst-case situation being ±12v.

So basically, your circuit is doing exactly what you would expect, given the op-amp you are using.

Comment: but the amplitude of the signal was fine for the IC, i think the degradation is related with the value of R2, look i made the same using r2 = 1k, and i get a sine signal according to the theory, but with r2 = 10k, the signal just change the form. I want to know why this change

Comment: @SebastianGriotberg - You're exceeding the range of voltages the op-amp can output. This is **independent of the gain**. You will have the exact same problem if you go back to R2 = 1K, and increase the amplitude of the input by 10 times.

Comment: Basically, if your *output voltage* exceeds ~±14v, **no matter what the value of R1 or R2**, the output will clip.

Comment: @ConnorWolf - Looking at the 'scope trace, Sebastians input is only 1V peak (not 2V peak as he says) so with R2=1k his output won't clip. Also, with R2=10k, his gain is 100 not 1000!

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - You're correct about the gain (whoops). However, the second scope trace is 5V/div. The output is swinging ~±13V, which is what you would expect. The input **is** 2V peak-peak (first image: 500 mV/div, 4 divisions peak-peak). However, he looks to have positive and negative rails, so the total supply voltage is 30v, or ±15V.

Comment: @ConnorWolf - Agreed with R2=10k, but if he reduces it to 1k the output would be ±10V and not clipped.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - Isn't that what he said happens?